# boolean inside a while statement after we have declared it to be false

Tags: java

im having a hard time to understand what !outOfGuesses means and what it does, heres the code

```
    String hiddenWord = "qwe";
    String guess = "";
    int tries = 0;
    int maxTries=5;
    boolean outOfGuesses=false;

    while(!guess.equals(hiddenWord) && !outOfGuesses) 
        if(tries<maxTries) {
        System.out.print("Find the word :");
        guess = input.nextLine();
        tries++;
        }
        else 
          outOfGuesses=true;
        {
    if(outOfGuesses)
        System.out.print("Out of tries.");
    else
        System.out.print("You won!");
```

Comment: `!` is the boolean not operator. So `!outOfGuesses` is true when `outOfGuesses` is false and vice versa.

Comment: This code has an unfortunate lack of braces `{}` for your `while` statement, but otherwise the variable named `outOfGuesses` is self-explanatory.

Comment: The code apparently seems to be of guessing a word in given number of tries. `outOfGuesses` is tracking, if a user has used all their tries or not. Also, this code will not compile.

Comment: @tin, if you are having difficulty understanding the code then put it into words. For example, the part `&& !outOfGuesses` means "AND NOT outOfGuesses" or "AND NOT OUT OF GUESSES".

Answer (score 0):

`!` is an operator, commonly called the "not operator", takes any boolean variable and returns the opposite.

```
boolean x = false;
boolean y = true;
x = !x; // x is false, !x is true
y = !y; // y is true, !y is false
```

so, in your example, `outOfGuesses` is set to false at the beginning, so `!outOfGuesses` would be true. You can think of it as "not out of guesses".

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

`!` is

> Logical complement operator;
> inverts the value of a boolean

`!outOfGuesses` will invert the value of `outOfGuesses` and `while` loop will evaluate the condition based on this inverted value.

It is equivalent to writing `outOfGuesses == false`.

Comment: how is it inverting when It is equivalent to writing outOfGuesses == false ? it is already false

Comment: Using `!outOfGuesses` in `while` condition means `while` checks for inverted value of `outOfGuesses` which can be written as `!outOfGuesses == true` or `outOfGuesses == false`.

Comment: why cant i use only `outOfGuesses` on the while statement if its already false ? is booelan outOfGuesses = false; equal to not outofguesses ? if not, why?

Comment: Only outOfGuesses in while condition will check for true value

Comment: thanks for the help , but i figured it out by changing the wording , i used stillHaveGuesses to understand it better and now i do